# Define Option in Text

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

So, I can't seem to be able to get the `define` option in my `UITextView` (well it's a custom view of sorts). Right now, I have this in my `CanPerformAction` method:

```
    - (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(copy:))
        return NO;

    if (action == @selector(delete:)) {
        return NO;
    }

    if (action == @selector(addHighlight:))
        return YES;

    if (action == @selector(showThinkFeed:))
        return YES;

    if (action == @selector(editHighlightNote:))
        return YES;

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

I don't get the define option this way. I tried putting `return YES;` on the method call and the define option does appear but when clicked on it, it throws an exception that says:

```
-[MyViewController _define:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14574200
```

Answer (score 1):

`_define:` is a **private** selector of `UITextView`. I guess, your custom view did not implement it.

However, be careful: if you use it it (i.e., implement your own) for an app you want to sell via AppStore, your app will be rejected due to the private character.

Comment: So you mean if we override the "canperformaction" method, we'll have to implement all the native methods? I want the native dictionary of Apple to be implemented on the text. Is there a way to do it? Note: This app is enterprise and I wouldn't really care about undocumented or private APIs but I am not too keen on developing my own custom definition view.. if you know what I mean.. Thanks for your reply..

Comment: @NSFeaster: Not all: the most (`copy:` etc.) are defined in `UIResponderStandardEditActions` (an informal protocol); overriding is recommended but not enforced. However, `_define` is not part of that very protocol.

Comment: So if I get this right, I now have no option of getting a define option at all? If I do, I would have to define the implementation of it it my class itself...?

Comment: Actually, I see two options: 1. Write an own `_define` 2. Derive your view from `UITextView`. 2a) delegate the call for `_define` to a "real" `UITextView`.